# How to place an element in different places of a page using only bootstrap code?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Put an element in the middle of the page using Bootstrap code?

```
<div class="container">
   <asp:Label id="label1" runat="server" text="Place me in center of a page">
   </asp:Label>
</div>
```

Comment: PLease, elaborate more your question

Comment: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/05/page/4/?setLocale=1